# maths - find vertices when 1 vertex and center point is given in polygon

Tags: geometry, triangles

I want to know if there is any general formula to find out vertices (co-ordinates) of a polygon (3 or more equal sides) when following is given:

```
Co-ordinates of one of the vertices 
Center point (distance between each vertex and center point is equal)
```

For example, what would be A and B vertices of following equilateral triangle:

(For equilateral triangle i assume that center point = centroid)

```
     A
    /\
   /  \                 Center point = (2, 5)
  /____\ 
 B      C (4, 6)
```

Thanks for help.

Regards

Comment: Yep, it's just a linear transformation ;)

Comment: I think you need more assumptions in your hypothesis.  With those assumptions alone, you still can't determine n, where n is the number of sides (or vertices) of your regular polygon.  If you look closely at the answers you've been given as well as at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularPolygon.html, you'll notice that it's assumed n is known.  However, you don't have that assumption in your hypothesis, which means those formulas won't work unless n can be found to depend on the coords of one vertex and the center.  (But I'm pretty sure that last part is impossible.)

Comment: The problem's underdetermined. At the very least, you want to be able to form the isosceles triangle that comprises a "slice" of the regular polygon you want, and just two pieces of information isn't enough to uniquely determine that triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a polygon with equal sides and equal distance from center to all vertices it seems to be a [regular convex polygon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularPolygon.html)

**EDIT** I've found much easier way.

Assume that center of the polygon has coordinates `(x_0,y_0)` and known vertice has coordinates `(x_n,y_n)`. Also assume that we are considering n-sided polygon.

Coordinates of i-th vertce (`0<i<n`) can be calculated using this formulae

```
x_i = x_0+R*cos(a+2*Pi*i/n)
y_i = y_0+R*sin(a+2*Pi*i/n)
```

where

```
     _______________________
R = v(x_n-x_0)^2+(y_n-y_0)^2
a = acos((x_n-x_0)/R)
```

According to your example computations using formula above shows that

```
A=(4, 6)
B=(0.1339745962155614, 6.2320508075688776)
C=(1.8660254037844377, 2.7679491924311228)
```

You can check (e.g. using [this](http://www.1728.com/distance.htm) calculator) that distances between `A` and `B`, `B` and `C`, `C` and `A` are the same and equal to `3.8729833462074166`. Also yu can calculate distance between center and each vertice and see that they all will be the same.

==================

That means you can find length of the side of such polygon using this formula
`a=2Rsin(Pi/n)`, where `R` is a distance between center `c` of your poly and its known vertice `p`.

```
   _____________________________
R=v(c.x - p.x)^2 + (c.y - p.y)^2
```

So you will have a triangle based on center `c` of your poly and its first `p` and second `s` vertices.  Since you know coordinates of `c` and `p` and length of all sides of this triangle (distance between `c` and `p` is `R`, distance between `p` and `s` is `a` and distance between `s` and `c` is again `R`) you can determine coordinates of `s`.

Comment: To get $a$, the starting angle, it is better to use $Atan2(y_n-y_0,x_n-x_0)$  Atan2 sorts out the quadrants for you, while for Acos you need to do it yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot for help @Konstantin Mikhaylov and @Ross Millikan. I used atan2 to find a. Thanks again. Regards