# Find vertices of a polygon given 1 vertex and the center point in 3D space

Tags: geometry, 3d, polygons

Is there a method to calculate the vertices of a polygon given just 1 vertex of the polygon and its center point? I found this post [maths - find vertices when 1 vertex and center point is given in polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35438/maths-find-vertices-when-1-vertex-and-center-point-is-given-in-polygon) on the topic, but it's only for 2 dimensions. Can this be extrapolated to 3 dimensions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the center of a (regular) polygon and one of the vertices, you can find infinitely many polygons in three-dimensional space.

To get a unique polygon, you'll need (say) another vertex to define the plane the polygon rests in.

Comment: That makes sense. If I have a third point, the midpoint of an edge (this edge is connected to the given vertex), how can I calculate the other vertices of the polygon?

Comment: @namcap I’d build the a polygon in the $x$-$y$ plane centered on the origin (which is almost trivial to do) and then apply a transformation to move it into position.